# скорость записи hibernate

Tags: java, sqlite, hibernate

Использую hibernate + sqlite. Очень много уходит времени на запись(чтение итд). На insert 100 строк уходит 1.8с. Может я что-то делаю не так или это нормальная задержка для hibernate?

```
public void insert(List<Buffer> buffers) throws SQLException {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        for (Buffer item : buffers) {
            session.save(item);
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}


<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:test.db</property>
    <property name="connection.username"></property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="maxActive">50</property>
    <mapping resource="User.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="Buffer.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="model.Buffer" table="buffers">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="int">
        <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>

    <property name="addrA" column="addrA" type="int"></property>
    <property name="addrB" column="addrB" type="int"></property>
    <property name="addrC" column="addrC" type="int"></property>

    <property name="name" column="name" type="string"></property>
    <property name="valName" column="valName" type="string"></property>
    <property name="measurements" column="measurements" type="string"></property>

    <property name="statusPriority" column="statusPriority" type="int"></property>
    <property name="value" column="value" type="string"></property>
    <property name="mistake" column="mistake" type="string"></property>
    <property name="dateEvent" column="dateEvent" type="calendar"
        not-null="false" length="7"></property>
    <property name="idEvent" column="idEvent" type="long"></property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        List<Buffer> buffers = getBuffers(100);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        BufferHibernate.getInstance().getBusDAO().insert(buffers);

        System.out.println("insert : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Попробовал запустить пример http://hibernate-sqlite.googlecode.com/files/HibernateSQLitewithjar.rar результат тот же, только теперь одна запись заняла 1.6с.

Самая большая задержка при открытии сессии 
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

Необходимо производить запись в базу каждую секунду в разных потоках. Думал перед каждой записью открыть сессию, записать и зарыть. Получается открытие тяжелое и должно быть открыто на время выполнения программы? Конфликтов не будет?

Comment: А объекты большие? Честно, не встречался с такими тараканами в больших бд.

Comment: Нет. Запись в одну таблицу, используются типы string, int, long, calendar. Всего 12 значений.

Comment: А если "голыми руками" запись вести - значения задержек те же? Точно в Hibernate дело?

Comment: пришли код, где вызываешь  insert

Comment: С sqlite работал в других проектах, скорость была нормальная.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {

  try {
   List<Buffer> buffers = getBuffers(100);
   long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
   BufferHibernate.getInstance().getBusDAO().insert(buffers);

   System.out.println("insert : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

Comment: используй Singlton для получения сессии. Хибернейт очень тяжелый и медленный. и Очень много памяти жрет. Сессию закрой когда она уже точно не нужна будет .
В своем проекте я один раз открываю сессию и закрываю при завершении

Comment: пробуй указать hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50 и посмотри на результат

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html